# "421 Active data channel timed out." with FTP client connection from Azure VM from SQL stored procedure

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-virtual-machine, sql-server-2016

We're migrating from a Windows server box to Virtual Machines on Azure. Our SQL stored procedure uses Integration Services packages to generate feed files and upload them to client ftp servers.

We do this by building script files and using the native `ftp.exe` client on Windows. My script file looks like this:

```
open ftp.ourserver.net
myusername
mypassword123
lcd G:\
cd /
prompt
put "G:\DataFeeds\SmithCo_02272017.txt" "SmithCo_DailyFeed.txt"
bye
```

This works fine on our old server. When I use command prompt to run this code I'm getting:

> 421 Active data channel timed out.

I can upload the file manually with just a basic connection using WinSCP client on that machine.

I thought it was a port issue so I created an outbound rule in Windows Firewall for port 21, allowed all connection.

Then I created an endpoint in Azure for port 21 as well.

Is there another step to open this up or something I may be missing?

Comment: Which mode of your FTP server? active or passive? If your FTP server is active mode, you should open ports N>1023 on the azure vm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows command-line `ftp.exe` supports the FTP active mode only. In the active mode, the server has to connect back to the client to establish data connection for a file transfer. More over the `ftp.exe` does not allow you to pick, what port is used for the data connection. It randomly picks any available port number above 1024. So you would have to create end points for all ports above 1024. That's possibly something you do not want to do. Though you can try.

WinSCP works, because it (as most modern FTP clients) uses the passive mode by default. For the passive mode, you do not need to open any ports on the client side.

Read my article about [network configuration for FTP active and passive connection modes](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ftp_modes) for details.

---

As WinSCP works for you, you can use [WinSCP scripting interface](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_automation) to replace your `ftp.exe` script.

It would be like (`ftp.txt`):

```
open ftp://myusername:mypassword123@ftp.ourserver.net/
lcd G:\
cd /
put "G:\DataFeeds\SmithCo_02272017.txt" "SmithCo_DailyFeed.txt"
exit
```

*(Though the `lcd` is redundant, both in your and WinSCP script).*

And run the script like:

```
winscp.com /script=ftp.txt
```

See the guide to [converting Windows FTP script to WinSCP script](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_ftp_script_to_sftp).

*(I'm the author of WinSCP)*

Comment: This seems like the best solution. I re-configured the stored procedure to use winscp.com and it's working great.  We generally send txt, csv, and xml files.  However, we occasionally send xls.   Do I need to set option transfer to binary or auto?  Or does it handle the distinction on its own?

Comment: WinSCP by the binary mode by default. That should be ok for any kind of files.